# Win10 Inaccessible Boot Device, later no bootable device found :(((

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios, bsod

i have a problem with Windows 10, after waking up my computer i get "Inaccessible Boot Device" [Blue screen] and for few minutes nothing happened, so i decided to restart it manually (by holding power button for few seconds) and later i get [black screen] with no bootable device found, even bios does not see my OS ssd. Do you have any suggestions, how can i fix this ugly problem?

Comment: Try resetting your BIOS to defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Many articles about "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" describe troubleshooting steps needed to fix a corrupt MBR or other disk issues. There is one possible cause for this issue which cannot be fixed this way - changing BIOS setting for the disk between IDE and AHCI mode.

This may happen by someone playing with the BIOS settings, or by BIOS resetting to the default settings.

To fix the issue try changing your disk controller mode from IDE to AHCI or vice versa for the disk which is used for booting the system.

My story:

I have two different disk controllers in my system (Intel and Marvell) and the system was configured to use RAID mode for the Intel controller and AHCI mode for the Marvell one. After I have replaced the power supply the BIOS reported low CMOS battery and reset all settings to their default values, which was IDE for both controller - the system would not boot then.

I had to go the BIOS and set the Marvell controller to AHCI again.